# expected declaration after if statement

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement

I have an "expected declaration" at this line:

```
if(userEmail.isEmpty || userPassword.isEmpty || userRepeatPassword.isEmpty)
```

Could you tell me why? Thank you in advance.

My code:

class RegisterPageViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var userEmailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var userPasswordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var repeatPasswordTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func registerButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let userEmail = userEmailTextField.text;
    let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text;
    let userRepeatPassword  = repeatPasswordTextField.text
}
```

// Check for empty fields

```
if(userEmail.isEmpty || userPassword.isEmpty || userRepeatPassword.isEmpty)
{

// Display Alert Message
displayMyAlertMessage("All fields are required");
return;

}
```

Comment: have you written the if statement inside the `registerButtonTapped ` method or outside this method?

Comment: well as you can see it is below registerButtonTapped.

Answer (score 2):

Declare the variables in the class or even globally, not inside the button!

```
var userEmail: String = ""
var userPassword: String = ""
var userRepeatPassword: String = ""
```

Button declaration:

```
@IBAction func registerButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    userEmail = userEmailTextField.text;
    userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text;
    userRepeatPassword  = repeatPasswordTextField.text
}
```

Comment: Where exactly is the if statement written? Show the whole code if you can.

Comment: Well that is the whole code the beginning and the end of it. I am going to add more things but I figured since it doesn't work now I'd stop.

Comment: Did you try writing the declaration of the variables below the outlet declaration?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(userEmail.text == "" || userPassword.text == "" || userRepeatPassword.text == "")
 {

      // Display Alert Message
      displayMyAlertMessage("All fields are required");
      return;

 }
```

or you can try

```
if(userEmail.text.isEmpty || userPassword.text.isEmpty || userRepeatPassword.text.isEmpty)
 {

      // Display Alert Message
      displayMyAlertMessage("All fields are required");
      return;

 }
```

try to check blank string and it will work the same

Comment: still expected declaration

Comment: @NicolasBilic it is working in my code so it should work in your code too.

Answer (score 0):

I put the if statement inside a function and it worked. 
Thank you for all your answers guys.
Like that:

```
func registerButtonTapped() {  
    let userEmail = ""
    let userPassword = ""
    let userRepeatPassword = ""

    // Check for empty fields
    if userEmail.isEmpty || userPassword.isEmpty || userRepeatPassword.isEmpty
    {
        // Display Alert Message
        displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage:"All fields are required")
        return
    }
```